# Scala pattern match is not exhaustive on nested case classes

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I've got a case class hierarchy to encode some request and processing errors:

```
  sealed trait OpError
  sealed trait RequestErrorType
  sealed trait ProcessingErrorType

  final case class InvalidEndpoint(reason: String) extends RequestErrorType
  final case class InvalidParameters(reason: String) extends RequestErrorType

  final case class InvalidFormat(response: String) extends ProcessingErrorType
  final case class EntityNotFound(id: Long) extends ProcessingErrorType

  final case class RequestError(errorType: RequestErrorType) extends OpError
  final case class ProcessingError(errorType: ProcessingErrorType) extends OpError
```

If I write a simple match across all patterns:

```
  def printMatches(error: OpError): Unit = error match {
    case RequestError(InvalidEndpoint(reason)) => //print something
    case RequestError(InvalidParameters(reason)) => //print something
    case ProcessingError(InvalidFormat(format)) => //print something
    case ProcessingError(EntityNotFound(entityId)) => //print something
  }
```

the compiler gives me a warning about missing match:

```
 match may not be exhaustive.
 It would fail on the following input: ProcessingError(_)
 def printMatches(error: OpError): Unit = error match {
```

But ProcessingError takes in a ProcessingErrorType with only two extensions: InvalidFormat and EntityNotFound, both which are accounted for in the pattern match. What am I missing?

Even more curious is that if I change the parameter type of  InvalidParameters or InvalidEndpoint to a String*, I don't get the error:

```
final case class InvalidParameters(reason: String*) extends RequestErrorType
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `printMatches(ProcessingError(new ProcessingErrorType{}))` it is not match any

Comment: this example violates the `sealed` contract.

Comment: In terms of the curious behaviour with the String* parameter, it sounds like Scala turns of exhaustive checking when a case class has a varargs parameter: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8178?jql=labels%20%3D%20exhaustiveness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug. [I filed a bug report for this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9630) and it has been since fixed for  Scala 2.12.0-M4.

Comment: see this comment for a workaround: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9630?focusedCommentId=73864&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-73864

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting! Unfortunately, I haven't found an answer. I've been revolving around http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#constructor-patterns but I haven't really found a valid explanation for what's going on.

Here's a simpler demo (hope you don't mind):

```
sealed abstract class ClassOne
case class ClassOneImpl() extends ClassOne

sealed abstract class ClassTwo()
case class ClassTwoImpl() extends ClassTwo

sealed abstract class Foo
case class FooOne(x: ClassOne) extends Foo
case class FooTwo(x: ClassTwo) extends Foo

def printMatches(st: Foo): Unit = st match {
  case FooOne(ClassOneImpl()) => println()
  case FooTwo(ClassTwoImpl()) => println()
}
```

I've observed that each of the following two modifications removes the warning:
1) Changing `FooOne` and `FooTwo` signatures so that instead of taking `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` they take `ClassOneImpl` and `ClassTwoImpl`
2) Removing `FooOne` or `FooTwo` so that there's only one case class extending `Foo` (which leads to only one case in pattern matching).

Perhaps we could submit an issue and see what they say?

Comment: I filed it as a bug https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9630 and it has since been fixed and closed! Yay! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can help the compiler with an unchecked annotation:

```
... = (error: @unchecked) match ...
```

but you should be sure, your match is exhaustive.

Comment: true, but I wanted the compiler to help me figure out invalid instances not the other way around. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think exhaustiveness matching works on a single inheritance level. 
`RequestErrorType` and `ProcessingErrorType` are part of the constructor where that exhaustiveness is not checked.

You can see it from the reading of the code, but it seem that compiler does not.

Comment: Say  I comment out the match for RequestError(InvalidParameters(reason))  from printMatches, then the compiler lets me know that I am missing that exact variation: "match may not be exhaustive. It would fail on the following input: RequestError(InvalidParameters(_))". So I guess the compiler can figure out some nested inheritance.